# Flash: Screenshot/save viewport image

Tags: flash, actionscript, screenshot, macromedia

Is there actionscript to enable a screenshot of a specific area of the screen? And possibly display this screenshot at a different stage?

Comment: Do you mean taking a screenshot outside of your flash application?

Comment: No, of storing a part of the scene as an image or movie clip and then displaying it.

Comment: Again, do you want to take a screenshot of your flash content or take s screenshot of the website that is around it? The first is easy, the second not.

Comment: screenshot of the flash content, but a specific area of the content. Then display again in a different position...

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use the [BitmapData](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/) object to draw the current pizels onto a new object.  The code might look something like this...

```
//Assuming x,y,w,h is the area you want to capture
//Create a new bitmap data object to store our screen capture
var bmp:BitmapData = new BitmapData(h, w);

//Draw the stage onto our bitmap data clipping at the correct points
bmp.Draw(stage, null, null, null, new Rectangle(x, y, w, h));
```